# C# get string from list

Tags: c#, string, list

I am trying to get a string from a list in c#, but can't find a way to do it. Heres my code

```
public class CurrentCondition
{
    public string cloudcover { get; set; }
    public string humidity { get; set; }
    public string observation_time { get; set; }
    public string precipMM { get; set; }
    public string pressure { get; set; }
    public string temp_C { get; set; }
    public string temp_F { get; set; }
    public string visibility { get; set; }
    public string weatherCode { get; set; }
    public List<WeatherDesc> weatherDesc { get; set; }
    public List<WeatherIconUrl> weatherIconUrl { get; set; }
    public string winddir16Point { get; set; }
    public string winddirDegree { get; set; }
    public string windspeedKmph { get; set; }
    public string windspeedMiles { get; set; }
}
    public class Data
{
    public List<CurrentCondition> current_condition { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to get, for example, the `temp_F` string from the `current_condition` list. How can I do this?

Comment: You have a class named Data? Really?

Comment: At least show us some fail tries

Comment: @MitchWheat yea i should really rename that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `current_condition` is a list, you would have to know which list index you are interested in.  Say you want index 0, you would write

```
Data data = new Data();
// Some code that populates `current_condition` must somehow run
string result = data.current_condition[0].temp_F.
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want all the temperatures from your list of CurrentCondition instances, you could do this easily using Linq:

```
List<string> temps = current_condition.Select(x => x.temp_F).ToList();
```

In light of the accepted answer, here's how to get a specific temperature with Linq:

```
string temp = current_condition.Where(x => x.observation_time == "08:30").FirstOrDefault(x => x.temp_F);
```

Comment: The updated answer doesn't actually give what the OP is looking for either, and is not in any way equivalent to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
current_condition.ForEach(cond => list.Add(cond.temp_F));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ElementAt(int) to access an object in a list.

```
String t = current_condition.ElementAt(index).temp_F;
```

Comment: Or... why not just use the array index?  No need to treat the `List<T>` as if it were an `IEnumerable<T>`.  This solution is O(N), whereas using the array index is O(1).

Comment: Yup. You are right. As lots of beginners are confused with treating a list like an array I thought it would be better to post the "long" version. But your code is faster.